# Assignment Suppression Character

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char text[20];
    int quantity;
    float number;

    printf("Enter the data: ");
    scanf("%s %*d %f", text, &quantity, &number);

    printf("\nOutput: %s %d %f\n", text, quantity, number);

    return 0;
}
```

**Is there a way to properly use assignment suppression?**

[Data Output - Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnmLR.png)

How can I make it delete the data from the variable "quantity" (%*d), and that it prints correctly.

Comment: "it prints correctly" print what?

Comment: What is your *expected* output?

Comment: Also [please do not post images of text because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Texts should be posted directly **as text** in your question.

Comment: What do you mean by "delete the data from the variable 'quantity'"?

Comment: @MikeCAT You see the data output that is an example, even if it prints the text, the one that it suppresses does not skip and it does not allow the assignment of the variable "number", I'm sorry if I don't explain myself well.

Comment: @SteveSummit The format code %*d, suppresses and does not assign the value to the variable "quantity" or that is what I am reading and learning, I could not tell you more.

Comment: @OnelVald's It suppresses and does not assign it to *anything*.  You don't need to mention the name of the variable you don't want to assign it to!  You probably just want `scanf("%s %*d %f", text, &number);`.  And as the other comments and answers here are saying, if you don't fill in a value for `quantity`, you probably dont want to try to print it out later.

Comment: @MikeCAT Thanks for the recommendation, I did not know about the images, they should fix that I guess, "The images say a thousand words"

Comment: @OnelVald's A picture is worth a thousand words, it's true, but a picture of 1,000 words takes something like 1,000 times the bandwidth of those raw words, and it ends up being much less convenient to use, since it's no longer manipulable as text.

Comment: @SteveSummit Bro you're right, hahahha, I had no idea, thanks for commenting, do you know if the assignment suppression if useful for something else?, there is more?

Comment: @SteveSummit I understand about the images, thanks for commenting bro, take care and good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use assignment suppression, don't supply an argument for that match:

```
scanf("%s %*d %f", text, &number);
```

As for "deleting" the value in `quantity`, C doesn't have such a concept.  Because it was not initialized, its value is *indeterminate*, so it should be initialized before printing it.

Answer (score 0):

`%*d` won't make it store what is read, so no pointer corresponding to that should be specified.

Also Now `quantity` is not initialized and have indeterminate value, so printing that makes no sense.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char text[20];
    float number;

    printf("Enter the data: ");
    scanf("%s %*d %f", text, &number);

    printf("\nOutput: %s %f\n", text, number);

    return 0;
}
```